# How to call a certain path in delete method Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Typically when I am using a delete link it will look something like this

```
<% @variable_name.each do |block| %>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', block, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

For the current project, I am unable to use the "block" path for delete.  I now need to call a path that is related to block, but not defined in it.  I was thinking something like this

```
<% @variable_name.each do |block| %>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', someother_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to link to a url instead of using a helper method?  If so how would I find that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the path helper:

```
someother_path(first_argument: 'whatever')
```

Also, if you want the full path of the link (including domain host + port), use this:

```
someother_url(first_argument: 'whatever')
```

The last option is to write the path as a string, for example:

```
link_to 'Destroy', "/posts/#{post.id}/destroy" # etc.
```

But this last option should not be used as it is complicated to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use any other urls as long as you defined the routes in routes.rb

in your routes.rb file

```
resources :variables do
  delete :someother, on: :member
end
```

then you can check the routes.
To check the urls, please run following command line in terminal.

```
rake routes
```

or

```
rake routes | grep variable
```

and you can do

```
<% @variable_name.each do |block| %>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', someother_variable_path(Variable.find_by_name(block)), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```